# Why are all Date elements in my array the same date?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have a very weird issue with Javascript. I am trying to loop through my date to do some checking and add value to my array, but when I return out the arrays, it shows all my collections with last value. Below is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var todayDate = new Date();
    var firstDay = new Date(todayDate.getFullYear(), todayDate.getMonth(), 1);
    var lastDay = new Date(todayDate.getFullYear(), todayDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
    var testDates=[];

        while (firstDay <= lastDay) {
            var currentDate = firstDay;

            testDates.push( firstDay);

            firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 1);
        }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testDates;
}
```

This ends up with last value for all my dates:

> Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00,Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00,Fri Jan 01 2016
>   00:00:00,Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00,Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00,Fri Jan 01
>   2016 00:00:00

Why does this happen?

Comment: You need to create new dates, not update the same object and push multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the date to your array, but a refference to the date. Then if you update the `firstDay`, you update the date of ALL elements in the array. (Because they all point to the same date). Try to clone the date like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var todayDate = new Date();
    var firstDay = new Date(todayDate.getFullYear(), todayDate.getMonth(), 1);
    var lastDay = new Date(todayDate.getFullYear(), todayDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
    var testDates=[];

    while (firstDay <= lastDay) {
        var currentDate = firstDay;

        testDates.push( new Date(firstDay.getTime()) );

        firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 1);
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testDates;
}
```

Comment: i see my mistakes. Thank you for pointing out my silly mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Making a little change to this comment: [Why are all Date elements in my array the same date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411372/javascript-while-loop-issue/34411492#34411492)

```
function myFunction() {
    // Using variables definition pattern
    var todayDate = new Date(),
        firstDay = new Date(todayDate.getFullYear(), todayDate.getMonth(), 1),
        lastDay = new Date(todayDate.getFullYear(), todayDate.getMonth() + 1, 0),
        currentDate = firstDay,
        testDates=[];

    // Change firstDay to currentDate in comparison part of the loop
    while (currentDate <= lastDay) {
        testDates.push( new Date(currentDate.getTime()) );
        // Also change firstDay to currentDate because it's a temporary
        // variable used to perform calculations and moving through
        // values
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testDates;
}
```

1) Variables definition pattern allows you to group definitions of variables in such a way that it's easier to read the code (look at the inвenеation);
2) In the original code this line
    var currentDate = firstDay;
does just nothing but only declares a variable which isn't used anywhere. It's also a bit incorrect to change the firstDay value because as it comes from the variable name, it shouldn't change. I believe currentDate was inteded to be used as a temporary one, just noticing that.